# Saving post contents to database using php

Tags: php, mysqli

Well, I am making a blog system, but I have a question.

For example I will use this code

```
$contents = $_POST['contents'];
$conn->query( "INSERT INTO `posts`(`content`) VALUES ('{$contents}')" );
```

What if the `$contents` contains `'`, This will cause an error.

So is there other way to upload text file to database skipping this error?

Comment: You should be using prepared statements instead.

Comment: if you are using `mysli_*` or `PDO`  then either `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or `prepared statements` will help you. check the php manual for those.

Comment: However, to answer this question, you can use the built-in function, `mysql_real_escape_string`.